# Is there any way to select specific speaker for android device?

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, audio-streaming, audio-recording

We are developing a VOIP application, there is one component which need to record the audio from mic, and play the remote audio to speaker. And we need to do some audio/signal processing for the recorded audio.

But on some android device, the selected mic and speaker is so near, the audio captured from MIC clipping (too loud) because of the audio played by speaker. This cause the captured audio waveform have nonlinear losses, and make the audio/signal processing component doesn't work.

We doesn't want to set `AUDIO_STREAM_VOICE_CALL` to enable build-in AEC, because it will make the recorded audio sample rate to be 8k while I'd like the recorded audio to be 48k.

So We have consider following solution:

- Decrease the mic volume. Base on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175902/how-to-ajust-microphone-volume-in-android) and [this discussion thread](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9913), it seams impossible.
- Using specific speaker and mic to make the distance a little bit far, so the mic captured audio volume is low.

So any way to select specific speaker on android platform?

Comment: What do you mean by saying specific speaker?

Comment: I mean the one which far away the speaker instead of the near one.

Answer (score 0):

If the distance between microphone and the speaker is crucial here maybe is would be enough to use camera's mic:

```
MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER
```